# SAP Web IDE warning: "The control ID is not defined. Enter a unique ID."

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I'm developing a UI5 app and right now I have the following problem: I've changed things somewhere recently and now it gives me the following error in a view:

[image: Screenshot of my XML view warning - SAP Web IDE]

> The control ID is not defined. Enter a unique ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either disable the [`XML_MISSING_STABLE_ID` warning](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/1666c1fc08b94f52913d9b17d22bcae3.html) in your SAP Web IDE or add `id="..."` accordingly to the controls to which the warnings refer.

I don't have access to SAP Web IDE anymore but as far as I can remember, you could decide which XML validator to use in your project. Go to the project settings and select the default XML validation instead of the SAP Fiori XML validator .